# Collection Filter Grouping - Customizing the User Experience

Tags: shopify, liquid

We would like to customize the collection group filtering. Currently, the group filtering is grouping and showing all product tags that have an underscore in the tag name.

ex: Brand_Premium

However, we would like to only show a filter group when there is more than one filter available within a group:

ex: All products on a given collection collection page are the same brand. In this case, we do not want to show a filter group for Brand, since there is only one option.

```
{%- capture tag_icon -%}
  <span class="filter-icon--checkbox">
    {%- include 'icon-checkbox' -%}
  </span>
{%- endcapture -%}

{% for cat_item in cat_array %}
  {% assign tag_count = 0 %}
  <h3 class="productgrid--sidebar-title--small">
    {{ cat_item }}
  </h3>
  <ul class="productgrid--sidebar-item filter-group">
    {% for tag in collection.all_tags %}
      {% assign cat = tag | split: '_' | first %}
      {% if cat != tag and cat_item == cat %}
        {% assign tag_count = tag_count | plus: 1 %}
        {%- capture tag_text -%}
          {{- tag_icon -}}

          <span class="filter-text">
            {{ tag | remove_first: cat | remove_first: '_' }}
          </span>
        {%- endcapture -%}

        {% assign filter_class = 'filter-item' %}
        {%- if current_tags contains tag -%}
          {% assign filter_class = filter_class | append: ' filter-item--active' %}
        {%- else -%}
          {% assign filter_class = filter_class | append: ' filter-item--inactive' %}
        {%- endif -%}

        {%- if tag_count > tag_limit -%}
          {% assign filter_class = filter_class | append: ' filter-item--hidden' %}
        {%- endif -%}

        <li
          class="{{ filter_class }}"
          data-tag-advanced
          data-group="{{ cat_item }}"
          data-handle="{{ tag | handle }}"
          {% if tag_count > tag_limit %}data-hidden-default{% endif %}
          {% if current_tags contains tag %}aria-current="true"{% endif %}
        >
          {% if current_tags contains tag %}
            {{ tag_text | link_to_remove_tag: tag }}
          {% else %}
            {{ tag_text | link_to_add_tag: tag }}
          {% endif %}
        </li>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

    {% if tag_count > tag_limit %}
      <li class="filter-item">
        <a class="filter-text--link" href="#" data-filter-toggle="false">
          {{ 'general.general.see_more' | t }}
        </a>
      </li>
    {% endif %}
  </ul>
<hr />
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You can check if `tag | handleize` is not same as `collection.handle` and continue

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not sure I understand the proposed solution. Can you provide a little more clarity?